Task schedule data flow , send current time stamp as argument
I’m using SCDF to create tasks and task schedules. My task accepts current timestamp as the job parameter. But I’m unable to pass the current timestamp using —arguments . Can anyone help me in creating a task schedule command which accepts an argument Runtimestamp=currentdatetime?
My task schedule command is like below :
task schedule create —-name schedule_name —definitionName task-name —expression “corn expression” —arguments “RUNTIMESTAMP=current_timestamp”
I want current timestamp to be yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss

To the issue above I can respond with a comment:
Are you wanting a timestamp for each time the app is launched via the scheduler?"
If so, there is no way to do this via SCDF, because SCDF relinquishes control of the execution of the task to scheduler.
However this can be done by adding some code within your application. Is this a Boot/Batch/Task App?  Or is it just a Boot/Task app?

Hi it’s a Spring cloud task and yes I want a current date time to be passed as argument each time the app is launched via a schedulerr

At this time I believe the best way is for the application to create its own timestamp.
